# My react-native application run correctly on android emulation 100% but it shown network error on physical device when I login or signup

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb, react-native, mobile

Database: MongoDB
App: react native
Node js
error: My react-native application run correctly on android emulation 100% but it shown network error on physical device when I login or signup.

Comment: Your real device and system both should be connected to the same wifi or network - or else it won't work.

Comment: Yes same network

Answer (score 1):

It is because your server ( node.js ) is not hosted. To run your application in other physical devices ( except emulator ) you have to host your server because any physical phone cannot work with your machine localhost API.

Comment: Oh thanks for information.. can you please write a steps to host node.js server

Comment: you can follow this 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uEVmD6n8Il0&t=200s